# ConnectionRefusedError on Sockets Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I was wondering if someone could help me please as I'm having an issue.

So I'm trying to do a chat using sockets, and I'm trying to enable multiple users to connect to the server but I'm getting this error when testing :

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

So here is what I do (everything is done on my local machine)

I start my server script on the following IP and Port : 127.0.0.1 - 5555

Then I start my first user by running the user script, and connecting to the following server :

```
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5555
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((ip,port))
```

and it works fine for the first user, it connects successfully to the server

but when I run the same script a second time (to mimic user 2) using the same IP and Port to connect to it shows me the Error.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong

Following the comments suggestions here is my server code:

```
import threading
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5555

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()
clients = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)  

        except:
            break


def recieve():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}")
        client.send('NICK'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        clients.append(client)
        print(clients)

        print(f'Nickname of the client is {nickname}')
        broadcast(f'{nickname} joined the Chat'.encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected to the Server!'.encode('ascii'))

        # Handling Multiple Clients Simultaneously
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


print('Server is Listening ...')
recieve()
```

Comment: Your server is probably not able to allow a second connection to its socket. Threading your server could be a solution.

Comment: You should upload your server code.

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError means there is no server with that IP address and port. Probably your server closed after the first connection.

Comment: just uploaded the server code

Comment: You don't go back and call `accept` again until you have sent, received, and sent to the other end.  If your client doesn't send anything back, you will block there and never accept another connection.  You should start the thread much earlier.

Comment: so should i thread the recieve function too ?